# Order MySQL table by two parameters

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have an SQL table called Waiting_List with the following columns:

> ID_Patient, Arrival_Time,Classification, Target_Time , Waiting_Order

- Arrival_Time: corresponding to the time the patient arrives to the clinic
- Classification: corresponding to an INT from 1 to 5, depending on the priority the patient has; 1 being the highest priority
- Target_Time : corresponding to Arrival_Time plus a certain number of minutes, which depends on the Classification that has been given to the patient
- Waiting_Order: which is the place of the patient in the waiting list.

I want to select the results in my table first ordered by Target_Time and, if two or more patients have the same Target_Time, I want the one with the highest Classification to be selected first, in order to be able to be able to assign to each patient a Waiting_Order. What is the most straightforward way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM Waiting_List ORDER BY Target_Time,Classification
```

Check [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2fcdf/2) and [ORDER BY Optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html)

Comment: Thanks for your input! I am fairly new to SQL and just now realized that it is not possible to use UPDATE along with SELECT to write the Waiting_Order of the patient by updating the row that is currently selected. Is there any way of doing that?

Comment: I am not clear about your requirement? Why you need to "use UPDATE along with SELECT to write the Waiting_Order of the patient by updating the row that is currently selected"! You should SELECT data from db and after processing UPDATE it in db. Why you need to combine both?

Comment: Nevermind it, I can present the waiting list ordered without even needing the column Waiting_Order. Still learning the basics :)

Answer (score 0):

Try as told by Damodaran

```
   Select * from Waiting_list order by Target_time, classification;
```

if and when required, you may specify ascending order or descending order using the keywords asc or desc. if nothing is specified then asc is default.

You may also like to visit http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp